# Missing Google Cloud Service Account by Google My Business API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-my-business-api

as i tried to implement the google my business api I also want to setup a pubsub notification.

As the docs say:
"Give at least pubsub.topics.publish permissions to mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com."
to be able to add a pubsub-topic from my gc-project as a notification object.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/notification-setup

This service account is not registred in my "IAM -> Serviceaccount"-Section. Does anyone know, how to handle this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the service account in IAM by adding the `mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com` e-mail address and grant the permissions afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Find `mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com` in IAM and grant permission `pubsub.topics.publish`. There might also be a role for pub/sub publishers availble.

Comment: as I already mention, there is no serviceaccount like mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com.